# How to combine normal php with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I already have a website that was built with core php . But now I wanna add some more features like fb connect and so on to it. I wish to use CodeIgniter for these new features. In that case, should I convert my old codes into CodeIgniter and then add new feature or is there any other way to add just the new features with CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a problem if that is my situation. If your site has huge functionality it would be a tedious job for you to transfer your code from old PHP -> CI. But if you're patient enough might as well give it a try. CodeIgniter's good BTW :). My English is not so good. Sorry! :\

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use CI for development. Initially it might be hassle to port your code from normal php to CI. That too done properly won't be much hassle.

Once you will move to CI, your code will be organized, then you can enhance features in future. It will make your task very easy.

If you only want to move to CI just to add facebook connect. There is not much difference adding faceebook connect in normal php or CI.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have name (function/classes/etc) collisions between your existing app and CI, I think it's a matter of importing CI's index.php into your app. You'd have to get a handle of the CI object from your app via `=& get_instance()` to be able to access CI stuff.

From there, it's a matter of replacing all `$this->(function name)` calls into `(your variable)->(function name)` from CI.

For example:

`$this->CI =& get_instance();`

Instead of calling `$this->load->view('welcome_message')`, you call `$this->CI->load->view('welcome_message')`

Disclaimer: I haven't really tried calling CI from within another application. I was operating under the premise that CI plugins/libraries are pretty much plain old PHP. See more here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

But I agree with the other responders, if you take your time porting your app to CI, it would potentially be easier in the long run.